# how to install software in a different location?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, installation, file-management

When I am installing software, I usually like to choose where it installs to, **other than** C:/Program Files...However, from time to time, I come across software that does not let you choose the install location...how can I get around this and choose the install location?

This is handy in situations such as multiple partitions or separate system and data partitions, etc...

Any ideas?

(using Windows 7)

Comment: I'd suggest hacking the registry using TweakUI but Windows 7 doesn't have an official TweakUI tool. I wouldn't suggest manually hacking the registry, it's not for the feint-of-heart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they don't give you the option then you probably can't - though I expect this is somewhat application dependent.

If they don't give you an option, the file paths are probably hard coded instead of being relative, making it impossible to change the path.

Comment: ya, that's what I thought...

Answer (score 2):

> If they don't give you an option, the
>   file paths are probably hard coded
>   instead of being relative, making it
>   impossible to change the path.

I agree with this one.
If you want to get rid off Program Files/ Program Files x(86) from your system partition. You may copy all Program Files to another(data) partition and symbolic link it back to your system partition.

Comment: Really, Windows 7 can symlink? Who says that Windows can't learn a thing or two from *nix. ;)